# LightGBM returns a negative probability

Tags: python, data-science, lightgbm

I've been working on a LightGBM prediction model for checking the probability of something.
I scale my data using min max scaler, I save it, and trained the model on the scaled data.

Then in real-time I load my model and scaler from before, and try to predict the probability of a new entry.
For some reason I'm getting a negative probability

Here's the code:

```
# Model Vars
learning_rate = 0.005
boosting_type = 'gbdt'
objective = 'rmse'
metric = ['balanced_accuracy_score', 'rmse', 'auc']
sub_feature = 0.5721
num_leaves = 3000
min_data = 500
max_depth = 22
max_bin = 12000


def createLGBM():
   # Read dataset
   dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\FullDatasetNoArson.csv')
   x = dataset.values  # returns a numpy array

   # Normalize Data
   min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
   x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
   
   # Save scaler
   joblib.dump(min_max_scaler, "Saved_Scaler")

   dataset = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
   X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:8].values
   y = dataset.iloc[:, 8].values
   
   # Initiate LGBM
   x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
   d_train = lgb.Dataset(x_train, label=y_train)
   params = {'task': 'train', 'learning_rate': learning_rate, 'boosting_type': boosting_type, 'objective': objective,
             'metric': metric, 'sub_feature': sub_feature, 'num_leaves': num_leaves, 'min_data': min_data,
             'max_depth': max_depth, 'max_bin': max_bin, 'num_threads': 7, 'is_training_metric': True, 'verbose': 1}

   clf = lgb.train(params, d_train, 2000, keep_training_booster=True)

   # Prediction
   y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)

   # convert into binary values
   for i in range(0, len(y_pred)):
       if y_pred[i] >= .5:  # setting threshold to .5
           y_pred[i] = 1
       else:
           y_pred[i] = 0

   # Accuracy
   accuracy = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)

   clf.save_model("lgb-model_" + str(accuracy) + ".txt")

   return "lgb-model_" + str(accuracy) + ".txt"


def predict(data):
   data = np.asarray(data)
   print(data)
   min_max_scaler = joblib.load("Saved_Scaler")
   data = min_max_scaler.transform(data)
   data = data[:, 0:8]
   model = lgb.Booster(model_file='lgb-model_0.7906763418553157.txt')
   print(data)
   pred = model.predict(data)
   return pred.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

So after reading more on the topic I realized that using a decision tree regression model, can return a negative value and that's fine.

My mistake though, if anyone finds this.. is that I tried using regression to calculate the probability of something happening , the correct way of guessing the probability for such a thing is to use Binary Log-loss classification (or Log-loss Regression).